# lodash count unique of field

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of 500 objects each object looks like this:

```
{name: 'Hello', phone_num: '1234'}
```

Now i wish to find out how many there is of each name.  So i wish to convert my array into the following:

```
[{name: 'Hello', count:15}, {name:'Marc', count:5}]
```

So i wish thinking of using `lodash` for this but looking at their documentation i haven't been able to find an answer.

They have something called `countBy` but it doesnt seem to be sufficient for this issue.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: so you only want to add count property to every object, not group anything?

Comment: `_.counBy(your_data, 'name')`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can make use of [groupBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) to group them by name and then [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) each grouped items to return the necessary count and names.

```
var result = _(data)
  .groupBy('name')
  .map((items, name) => ({ name, count: items.length }))
  .value();
```

```js
var data = [
  { name: 'Hello', phone_num: '1234'},
  { name: 'Hello', phone_num: '1234'},
  { name: 'Hello', phone_num: '1234'},
  { name: 'Hello', phone_num: '1234'},
  { name: 'Hello', phone_num: '1234'},
  { name: 'Hello', phone_num: '1234'},
  { name: 'Hello', phone_num: '1234'},
  
  { name: 'Marc', phone_num: '5432'},
  { name: 'Marc', phone_num: '5432'},
  { name: 'Marc', phone_num: '5432'},
  { name: 'Marc', phone_num: '5432'},
  { name: 'Marc', phone_num: '5432'},
  { name: 'Marc', phone_num: '5432'},
  { name: 'Marc', phone_num: '5432'},
  { name: 'Marc', phone_num: '5432'},
  
  { name: 'Sam', phone_num: '76532'},
  { name: 'Sam', phone_num: '76532'},
  { name: 'Sam', phone_num: '76532'},
  { name: 'Sam', phone_num: '76532'}
  
];
  
var result = _(data)
  .groupBy('name')
  .map((items, name) => ({ name, count: items.length }))
  .value();
  
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.12.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:**

The ES5 Version would be:

```
var result = _(data)
  .groupBy('name')
  .map(function(items, name) { 
     return { name: name, count: items.length };
  }).value();
```

Comment: It means that the environment you're using javascript with is not compatible with ES6 arrow functions, let me add the ES5 version.

Comment: is `{name}` equals to `{name: name}`? How calls this? can you give a link to spec?

Comment: @vp_arth check [enhanced object literals](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#enhanced-object-literals)

Comment: Thanks) `{[a]: true}` is killer-feature :)

Comment: didn't know about using lodash as a constructor function (`_(data)`). I didnt see it in the documentation. Does it just converts js objects and arrays to lodash   object, so I can chain the functions, instead of passing js objects or arrays as an argument?

Comment: @Wish It is in the [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#lodash).

Answer (score 11):

My version:

```
var result = _(data)
  .countBy('name')
  .map((count, name) => ({ name, count }))
  .value();
```

Comment: This is a lot better than my solution. +1.

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Probably you have to rewrite it from es6 to es5

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
const data = [{name: 'Hello', phone:15}, {name:'Marc', phone:5}, {name: 'Hello', phone:10}];
const names = _.countBy(data, 'name');

Object.keys(names).map(x => ({name: x, count: names[x]}));
```

ES5 code:

```
var data = [{name: 'Hello', phone:15}, {name:'Marc', phone:5}, {name: 'Hello', phone:10}];
var names = _.countBy(data, 'name');

Object.keys(names).map(function(x) {
  return {
    name: x,
    count: names[x]
  };
});
```

Then you could assign the return of the `Object.keys` call to a var or do anything you want with it

Comment: that's ES2015 arrow function, it's on the new (not so new) JS version. i will edit the answer to add a ES5 version too

Comment: [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)